# MVC4 Hiding links with a custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I've been digging around for a while now trying to figure out how to use my custom AuthorizeAttribute class in my view to show and hide links.  I'm transitioning from IsInRole to the custom AuthorizeAttribute because I want the end user to select which groups are authorized to perform certain tasks.  Up to this point I've been using:

```
        @{ if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("UserMgr"))
           { Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.pkRecID }); }
        }
```

Where UserMgr is a domain group.  (this does work but is not what I need to do)

I then created a custom AuthorizeAttribute class:

```
    public class isAuthorized : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string Access { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        string[] aszList = Access.Split(',');

        if (!authorized)
        {
            // The user is not authenticated
            return false;
        }

        var user = httpContext.User;
        if (user.IsInRole("Admin"))
            return true;

        var rd = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
        var id = rd.Values["id"] as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            // Now id was specified => we do not allow access
            return false;
        }

        foreach (string szGroup in aszList) // check to see if user is in group
        {
            if (user.IsInRole(szGroup))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

This works in my controller to block access to functions but how do I hide links in my views using this function?

Thanks!

Comment: you mean hiding elements from within the cshtml so that only users with higher rights can see it?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I want to hide links and buttons in my cshtml based on if they have rights to use it as provided by the above class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an extension method, so you can apply it on the MvcHtmlStrings in your Cshtml file
Example:

```
public static IHtmlString If(this IHtmlString value, bool evaluation)
{
    return evaluation ? value : MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

Then on your html Element you can use it like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Reports", "Index", "Report").If(User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin"))
```

**UPDATE**

Steps:

1. Create a new static class in your project.
2. Add the suggested extension method to the newly created class.
3. To make this static class available in all cshtml views go to the webconfig located in the Views folder.
4. Again pay attention so that the web config is in the views folder, do NOT edit the one thats at the root of your app.
5. There add the namespace where your static class is located just like in the example below.

   ```
   <system.web.webPages.razor>
     <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
     <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
     <namespaces>
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
       <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" /> 
       <add namespace="YourApplication.Utils"/>  <!-- THIS IS THE EXAMPLE ON HOW TO INSERT THE NAMESPACE THAT CONTAINS YOUR STATIC CLASS --> 
       <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Helpers"/>
     </namespaces>
     </pages>
   </system.web.webPages.razor>
   ```

I cant explain it better then this.

Comment: I understand where you are going with this but how does it apply to my authorize function?  Also do I put this with my helper class or in each of my controllers?

Comment: Well, instead of User.IsInRole, you can use your authorize method. And for utility extension methods i recommend a static class, that holds helpers like these. Its the cleanest way i found.

Comment: I really understand what you are saying and its exactly what I want to do; thanks!  However, I'm still not sure where the extenion method is placed?  If I put it in my custom AuthorizeAttribute I get an error extension methode must be defined in a non-generic static class.  And it's not found in my .cshtml if I put the function in my controller.

Comment: Thanks, Freeman.  I've got that already.  If I try adding the extension method to my custom authorize class I get "extension method must be  defined as a non-generic static class" which triggered me to put in a static declaration in the class: public static class isAuthorized : AuthorizeAttribute.  But I then Iget the error: extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class.  Thanks for your help; I really appreciate it!

Comment: listen, dont put the suggested helper method in the same class as the authorize class, create a new one for it.

Comment: BTW, this is super slick and very elegant.